# C++ code won't compile on VS code even after installing all the extensions/packs and MingGW

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

So I installed VS code with all the packs/extensions and MingGW properly referring to Code with Harry tutorial step by step for windows 10 carefully but still getting this error.
Find Pic underneath.
[image: The error says 'warning: character constant too long for its type']

Code and ERROR MESSAGE:

```
CODE-->
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout<<'hello world';
    return 0;

}

ERROR MESSAGE
[Running] cd "c:\Users\Divyansh Singh\OneDrive\Desktop\apna folder\" && g++ tute1.cpp -o tute1 && "c:\Users\Divyansh Singh\OneDrive\Desktop\apna folder\"tute1
tute1.cpp:4:11: warning: character constant too long for its type
     cout<<'hello world';
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1869769828
[Done] exited with code=0 in 2.284 seconds
```

Comment: please include code and error message as text in the question

Comment: the error message does not match the code. You are not compiling the code you think you compile

Comment: I agree the error message said you used the wrong type of quotes for a string literal. Instead you tried to create a multi-character literal which is not going to work and not what you want. That does not match the code from the screen. Perhaps you were compiling some old version of the code that had that error. This is odd. In either case you will most likely need to investigate this. I highly doubt that we can help.

Comment: Did you copy and paste the source code from a word processor or email program into the editor?  If you did, don't do that.  Type the code in manually.  The usage of those quote characters smells of a copy/paste from an external program.

Comment: in the image it is `"` in the code you posted it is single quotes

Comment: Is it '' (as in single quote single quote) hello world '' (as in single quote single quote) ? It needs to be double quote "(one character) hello world double quote "(one character).

Comment: `std::cout<<'hello world';` is wrong but `std::cout<<"hello world";` is correct. I am unsure why your picture of the screen shows it as correct but with the error at the same time seems like you were not compiling the code you show. `'` is used for a single character. `char letter = 'a';` and `"` is for a string literal. `std::string myName = "John";` You need to use the proper quotes for both unlike some languages that let you use either.

Comment: It shows the same error whether I use single quotes (') or double quotes(")